# debian wheezy switches from internal to external monitor after AMD proprietary installation

Tags: debian, xorg, monitors, amd-graphics

First I would like to say that this is my first try to set up a linux distribution. With taking Debian 7.8 I was probably over estimating myself.
I do have the following video card:

`lspci -nn | grep VGA`

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Whistler [AMD Radeon HD 6600M Series]`

After the installation I just experienced a black screen. But with the help from [wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) I was able to get rid of the black screen and use Gnome3.But first I had a black screen too, but this time the issue was that during the initialisation the display switches to external monitor. So I plugged in a HDMI cable and I could see that my Gnome3 was working properly.

I would like to achieve that when no external monitor cable is plugged in, the monitor does not switch to external. On the other hand it would be nice if it switches to the external monitor if I plug in an external monitor. I do think that this can be achieved by manipulating the xorg.conf file, but sadly I do not know how.

**EDIT**

`xorg.conf` looks like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
            Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
            Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
    EndSection

    Section "Module"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
            Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
            Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
            Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
            Option      "DPMS" "true"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
            Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
            Driver      "fglrx"
            BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
            Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
            Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
            Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
            DefaultDepth     24
            SubSection "Display"
                    Viewport   0 0
                    Depth     24
            EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

Using display in the system settings I was not able to switch to my laptop monitor. I can change the settings for my external monitor and can only mirror the output on my laptop monitor. If you need information, let me know.